# 'Pages' not showing in Settings after successful pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy basic html files to a Gitlab page.

I've been using [the documentation](https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html) and I've cloned [this repo](https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html) and the only changes have been when I added my own html files to the `public` directory.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file content:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - master
```

The pipleine succeeds and according to their documentation I should see a pages link in the Settings but this never seems to show.

Appreciate any tips/advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the image missing. Thats enough, it works for me.

```
image: alpine:latest

pages:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  script:
  - echo 'Nothing to do...'
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public/
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Do you keep your source files in the public directory by default?  My current structure is:  .gitlab-ci.ym, README.md, and public folder with html inside.

Comment: Yes, my html files in public directory. If you have public folder and html folder inside, I think you should try username.gitlab.io/project/html url format.

Comment: Okay, unless I'm missing something (quite possible that I am) - do I set the url format once the pages are created? I've just started over with a repo using the above with my files in public and it's still not generating the page.

Comment: Think I've found what the issue was, I was trying to run from a sub directory on GitLab and it didn't seem to like it. Created a new repo higher up and it seemed to work fine.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Marked above as approved answer as this works. I was trying to run this in a sub-group and this isn't allowed.